# How to determine if a UIViewController has been called as ModalDialog?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog

In my app I can call a UIViewControle in both mode: Push and  ModalDialog.

How can I determine, once the UIViewController is active, if has been called as Push or Modal Dialog ?

Comment: I used the solution here, which handles cases where the view controller is presented inside a navigation/tab controller http://stackoverflow.com/a/6349300

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to determine whether ViewController is presented as Modal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798653/iphone-is-is-possible-to-determine-wheteher-viewcontroller-is-presented-as-moda)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check `modalViewController` property of parent view controller like this:

```
if ([self.parentViewController.modalViewController isEqual:self]) {
    NSLog(@"Modal");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Push");
}
```

Just remember to check it after the view has been pushed/presented.

Comment: This doesn't work from IOS 5+ because UIViewController does not answer for parentViewController anymore, but to presentingViewController instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798653/iphone-is-is-possible-to-determine-wheteher-viewcontroller-is-presented-as-moda

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
   if(self.presentingViewController){
        //modal view controller 

    }else{


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you haven't figured this out yet, I'll share my situation and how I detected whether I'm in a modal view controller.

I have a segue which presents a view controller modally. This view controller is embedded in a navigationController so that I inherit all the good UIBarButtonItem capabilities.

```
if ([self.parentViewController.presentingViewController.modalViewController isEqual:self.parentViewController]) {
   NSLog(@"I'm in a modal view controller!");
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The thing is the viewController may not be presented itself, but the collection view controller that contains it is. Maybe more general case will be useful for somebody:

```
- (BOOL)isModal {

    return self.presentingViewController.presentedViewController == self
    || (self.navigationController != nil && self.navigationController.presentingViewController.presentedViewController == self.navigationController)
    || [self.tabBarController.presentingViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]; 
}
```