# UIViewController check for showing modal view?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I need to check if the view controller is showing a modal view or not. And when a modal view is being shown, how can I intercept the "hide event" of the view controller's own view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>Not sure about what "view event" you are talking about, but</del> you can check for `modalViewController` property (which is deprecated in iOS 5) or `presentedViewController` property which is "the new black" in iOS 5.

Comment: Thanks I tried, it is ok. And Is it possible to show new view controller after the presented disappears?

Comment: If you want to show to consequent modal view controllers then the best place to show the second modal view controller is in the first modal view controllers `viewDidDisappear` method.

Comment: It is not possible. Because it is a 3rd party view presented on my tab bar controller

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about what you ask but :

to know if you're currently a modal view  check this link :

[Is it possible to determine whether ViewController is presented as Modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798653/iphone-is-is-possible-to-determine-wheteher-viewcontroller-is-presented-as-moda)

and to handle "hide event" use :

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```