# Is there a way to detect how many modal view controllers are being presented?

Tags: ios, cocoa, presentmodalviewcontroller

In iOS, presenting a `modalViewController` is super easy:

```
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Or:

```
[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Within a `modalViewController`(such as `navigationController`), you can present a `modalViewController` again. Is there a way to detect how many modal view controllers are being presented? Otherwise maybe hooking the  `presentModalViewController:animated:` and `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` would be a good idea? Thanks!

Comment: What's the goal? Maybe if you tell us the point of knowing that, we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a way to find the top most viewController, which should help resolving this question:

```
+ (UIViewController*)getTopMostViewController {
    UIWindow * window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UIViewController *appRootViewController = window.rootViewController;
    UIViewController *topViewController = appRootViewController;
    while (topViewController.modalViewController != nil) {
        topViewController = topViewController.modalViewController;
    }
    return topViewController;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Check this question:

[Is it possible to determine whether ViewController is presented as Modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798653/is-it-possible-to-determine-whether-viewcontroller-is-presented-as-modal)

You can use that code to "climb up" your views until you find a view that is not a modal view controller. Like:

```
while (isModal)
{
    currentViewController = currentViewController.presentingViewController;

    ...
}
```